# Implication from definition of characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, characteristic-polynomial, cayley-hamilton

I know that the characteristic function of a linear map $T:V\to V$ is defined as $\chi_T(x):=\chi_A(x)$ where $A$ is any matrix for $T$ w.r.t. some basis of $V$. I know this is well-defined as it is independent of choice of basis.

**My Question:** With $A$ a matrix for $T$, why does it follow that if $\chi_A(A)=0$ then $\chi_T(T)=0$?

I need this for the final step of my proof of Cayley-Hamilton.

Comment: Because multiplying a vector $v$'s coordinates with the matrix $A$ is same as transforming $v$ with $T$.

Comment: @UmeshShankar So when someone says that $A$ is a matrix for $T$ does this mean that $Tv=Av$?

Comment: Yes, $A.v=T(v)$

Comment: $T(v)=Av$ doesn't really make sense, except for very special examples. It should rather be something like $[T(v)]_B=A[v]_B$, where $[\cdot]_B$ is denoting the column of coordinates of what is inside, in the (ordered) basis $B$.

Comment: If $\chi_A(A)=0$, then for all $v\in V$ you have $[\chi_T(T)(v)]_B=[\sum_k a_kT^k(v)]_B=\sum_k[T^k(v)]_B=\sum_k A^k[v]_B=\chi_A(A)[v]_B=0$. Therefore, for all $v\in V$, $\chi_T(T)v=0$, since its coordinates are zero. This in turn means that $\chi_T(T)$ is the zero linear transformation. Here $B$ is the basis in which $A$ is the matrix of $T$ and $\chi_A(x)=\sum_ka_kx^k$.

Answer (score 1):

A concise way to summarize what's going on here is that, for any fixed basis $B$ of $V$, the map
$$T\mapsto[T]_B$$
which sends $T$ to its matrix with respect to $B$ is an isomorphism from the ring of linear transformations of $V$ under composition to the ring of $n\times n$ matrices over the base field $F$ under matrix multiplication, where $n=\dim V$. Therefore if $\varphi(x)\in F[x]$ is any polynomial,
$$[\varphi(T)]_B=\varphi([T]_B)$$
Taking $\varphi$ equal to the characteristic polynomial answers your question.